# php geocoding with dynamic address entry

Tags: php, geocoding

I'm trying to implement the google geocoding feature on my website where it automatically displays the dynamic address entry from the database.

Here is a javascript code I was able to get from the google examples

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}
</script>
```

and the html

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 480px; background:#ccc; position:relative; float:left;"></div>
<div style="position:relative; float:left;">
<input id="address" type="textbox" value="<?=$row['event_location']?>">
<input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
```

N.B. the $row['event_location'] is the address loaded from the database.

This code works just fine. Problem is, it loads a default location and doesn't show the address from my db until I use the Encode button.

I want it to load the address from the database by default. Thanks.

-----EDITED-----

In response to the addition of windows onload i added this function just before the end of the closing script tag

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

then i changed it to the codeAddress function but it didn't work.

Comment: do u mean call the function codeAddress() after page load instead of clicking the button?

Comment: ok so I write the answer. In case the answer is right and solve just mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this function...

```
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

with this...

```
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                defaultLocation = results[0].geometry.location;
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
                      zoom: 8,
                      center: defaultLocation
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Could not find you on the map, the reason is: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so u can call the function codeAddress after the page (i.e. just before the end tag body) load instead of click the button.

Comment: still didn't work. I would have to load the intialize function first.